# How to rotate a photo 90 degrees in SSRS - image data being imported by SQL query

Tags: sql, visual-studio, reporting-services, photo, varbinary

Seems like there's no way to do this without implementing custom code? Of which I have very little experience doing and need a step by step overview.

I'm building a report in SSRS (through visual studio) where the datasource is a query in SQL and the image columns are being generated as `varbinary` datatype.

I can import and view the images fine when the report renders however every photo imported is displayed landscape and flipped 90 degrees (even though according to our developers the photos are going into the database in a portrait manner). How can I flip the photo in SSRS so that it comes out in a portrait fashion instead of sideways? Is there a relatively easy way?

Comment: I created many reports that pull images from a database in the format you stated and they always come out the way they are saved. You could try an independent image viewer such as https://www.yohz.com/siv8_details.htm  to be certain.

Comment: image viewer was helpful... I think there's a possible issue with the images being in sql. Some aren't showing on the viewer, others are and ARE in portrait mode so I'm not sure why they showed previously in SSRS in a landscape format?

Comment: If they are in a text mode, check the writing mode, by default they should render as saved but this may have been changed. As a debug process, I would create a new report and just insert a single image from the database without changing anything else. Not sure what else I can offer.

Comment: @AlanSchofield Where do you check the writing mode?

Comment: Sorry my mistake, that's only textboxes and even if you add the image as the textbox background it will not rotate it..

Comment: @AlanSchofield Ok different question. Do you use the below system drawing code as a reference in any report to view a picture? I can't get any of them to view at the moment and I'm wonder if this has something to do with it.
System.Drawing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a

Comment: I don't reference any assemblies directly, I just use the designer in Visual Studio 2015 with SSDT.

Comment: Anyone with example, as an answer ?